# About windows authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, asp.net-authorization, asp.net-authentication

I enabled windows authentication for `asp.net mvc` project. I'm in company domain, and when I send an get request to server side, I don't see any special stuff like username/pwd in header/body. How does server know who am I? And if I send an ajax call to server, do I need to include username/pwd as part of this call? Please help.

Comment: Can you please explain what you have done so far? your web.config for authentication, any other authentication related changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrated Windows Authentication uses Negotiate (Kerberos) or NTLM authentication work the same way that Basic Authentication works.

When you send an initial request, the server responds with a 400 not authorized response. The browser sees the accepted types of authentication, and prompts the user for the username/password, or if it knows how to use the current windows login token and is configured to do so, it uses that token automatically.

[NTLM Working from Fiddler Perspective](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chiranth/archive/2013/09/21/ntlm-want-to-know-how-it-works.aspx)